# How can I create a custom UITableViewCell similar to the first section under Me tab in Twitter iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, uitableview

I am trying to recreate the a section of a UITableView that looks like the first section under the Me tab in the Twitter app for the iPhone. I am having trouble creating a UITableViewCell with views underneath it (like Tweets, Following, and Followers) that a user can tap to show another view. Any help or insight into how to achieve this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: They are both custmized UITableViewCells. It seems the second row has three UIButtons, and the first row has two UILabel's and a UIImageView. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I hadn't considered that it was two rows. I was trying to recreate it with 1 row. The other thing I am having trouble with as I have seen other people have the same issue is how to create the drop shadow for the cells?

Comment: That's a customized UITableView and UITableViewCell. You need to do more research. Here is a start point: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have read through this document and several others about implementing custom drawing. The problem with creating the drop shadow for each UITableViewCell is that the drop shadow turns in slightly at each cell divider giving and uneven look to the drop shadow. Twitter's UITableView has an even drop shadow all the way down. I probably will have to do this with images.

Comment: Yes if you use plain image with shadows then all could look even and fine. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an object subclass of UITableViewCell, and then add whatever UI elements you want to the view.

If the custom cell is supposed to contain certain data, make each variable a property so that it can be easily set from within the UITableViewDatasource.

Do this my creating a new file, and making it a subclass of UITableViewCell. I personally don't use interface builder at all, so if you want to code it manually, replace the initWithNib function with this one:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if(self){
    //Add custom views here
}
```